# AngularJS dependency injection implantation methods

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

Please see below, are those 2 samples of **dependency injection** basically equal in what they are doing or have I missed something important in my life?

**Code sample #1**

```
angular.module("app", []);
function Controller($scope, SomeService) {
   // do stuff
}

Controller.$inject = ['$scope', 'SomeService'];
```

**Code sample #2**

```
angular.module("app", [])
.controller("Controller", [ '$scope', 'SomeService' function($scope, SomeService){
    // do stuff
}]);
```

Comment: @musically_ut - thanks - that was a typo

Answer (score 1):

These two pieces of code are not the same.

```
angular.module("app", []);
function Controller($scope, SomeService) {
   // do stuff
}

Controller.$inject = ['$scope', 'SomeService'];
```

Does not add the controller into the module (namespace) `app` though it does declare that the `app` module exists.  Also, I do not think that this code will run.  See below for how to use this style of injection.

```
angular.module("app", [])
.controller("Controller", [ '$scope', 'Service' function($scope, SomeService){
    // do stuff
}]);
```

The second form uses the shorthand `.controller()` method to create the controller and inject the resources. You can then `angular.module('app')` to pull a reference to the named controller.

To manually inject into a controller follow this style:

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .factory('someService', function($window) {
    return {
      serve: function(text) {
        $window.alert(text);
      }
    };
  });

var injector = angular.injector(['app', 'ng']);

function Controller($scope, someService) {
  $scope.doStuff = function() {
    someService.serve('Doing stuff');
  };
}

injector.instantiate(Controller);
```

For a complete example see: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

Comment: Good point, but my question was regarding the Controller.$inject & dependency injection

Comment: oh, then they are the same.  Both are safe from minification errors.

Comment: I am looking at this a little closer.  I don't use the first syntax and I want to be sure it is correct

Comment: Better answer coming up.  Give me a minute

Comment: As opposed to using the Module("app").directive() Module.service, etc... Builder pattern that is typically how you put components together.  It is safer for minification and its a much more readable and less error prone. See: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module If you read the dependency injection link above, you will see that DI is actually complicated but that complexity is largely hidden when you use the Module helper methods